# Design Time DbContext Factory - Class Library how to get connection string from UserSecrets in a class library project?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have separated my Database project as a class library. And I am defining a `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation. I want to use `user-secrets` to keep the config settings. I get an error as follows. How can i make this setup work?

Note: I have already setup the user-secrets for the class library project. And my user secrets has the necessary values:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings:CatalogDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Catalog;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Project Structure:

```
Catalog
|---API(Web API)
|---Data(Class Lib)
    |- appsettings.json
    |- IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<CatalogDbContext>
```

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CatalogDbContext": ""
  }
}

public class CatalogDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<CatalogDbContext>
{
    public CatalogDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(CatalogDbContext));
        dbContextOptionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new CatalogDbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

This command fails with an error:

```
Catalog.Api> dotnet ef migrations add Catalog.Initial --project ..\Catalog.Data\Catalog.Data.csproj --verbose

Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'CatalogDbContext'.
Using DbContext factory 'CatalogDbContextFactory'.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
```

I can clearly say this is because the connectionstring is empty. The user secrets configuration provided is not added to the list of providers. I don't know what the setup will look like to add user secrets to a class library project. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried as you mentioned and repeated your error in my case

[image]

then I modified the appsettings.json in webapi project and  added the migration successfully this time,it  still read the jsonfile in your webapi project

[image]

Comment: Hey! yes I just figured it out but this is a significant discovery i made given the amount of time it took for me to realize. Yes, i played around with the config files between the `Data` project and the `WebApi` project. Finally i discovered that the `ef add migration` accepts a `--startup-project` whose purpose is to provide config settings. cool! it means the connection string will be picked up from the `--startup-project` and this is where we need to add the `appsettings.json` file that contains the `connection string`!!